# How to align a window on right side with flexible height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**Hey!**

As you see in the picture I want to move the existing chatwindow to the right side where the red box is.
And I also need the box to change the height of itself when the window is made smaller.

The grid is from semantic.ui.

EDIT: On some request the whole css and parent html container is given. Hope this helps to solve the problem.

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="two column doubling ui grid">
  <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">
        1
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="computer only column">
        <div class="chat_window">
            <div class="top_menu">
                <div class="buttons">
                    <div class="button maximize">
                        <h4 id="Online"></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="title">Chat</div>
            </div>
            <ul class="messages"></ul>
            <div class="bottom_wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="message_input_wrapper"><input class="message_input" placeholder="Type your message!" /></div>
                <div class="send_message">
                    <div class="text">Send</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message_template">
            <li class="message">
                <div class="avatar"></div>
                <div class="text_wrapper">
                    <div class="msgname"><a id="steamlink" target="_blank"><p id="msgname"></p></a></div>
                    <div class="text"></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .chat_window {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 450px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.top_menu {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.top_menu .buttons {
    margin: 3px 0 0 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
.top_menu .buttons .button {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.top_menu .buttons .button.close {
    background-color: #f5886e;
}
.top_menu .buttons .button.minimize {
    background-color: #fdbf68;
}
.top_menu .buttons .button.maximize {
    background-color: #a3d063;
}
.top_menu .title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #bcbdc0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#Online{
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    color: #bcbdc0;
}

.messages {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 20px 10px 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 600px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.messages .message {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    opacity: 0;
}
.messages .message.left .avatar {
    background-size: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.messages .message.left .text_wrapper {
    background-color: #DFDFDF;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
.messages .message .avatar {
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
border-radius: 50%;
display: inline-block;
}
.messages .message .msgname {
font-weight: bold;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    width: calc(100% - 85px);
    min-width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.messages .message .text_wrapper .text {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 250;
}

.bottom_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    bottom: 0;
}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #bcbdc0;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.bottom_wrapper .message_input_wrapper .message_input {
    border: none;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    position: absolute;
    outline-width: 0;
    color: gray;
}
.bottom_wrapper .send_message {
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #563D7C;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.2s linear;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
}
```

Picture:

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbzdN.png)

Comment: I'd argue that the HTML and CSS you provided are insufficient to solve your problem. Please supply the HTML and CSS including the parent container.

Comment: Added the whole script. :)